# Uniqueness of the parameters of an Ito process, given initial and terminal conditions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Sufficient conditions for the existence and uniqueness of a weak solution of a stochastic differential equation $$dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma dZ_t$$ are known.  Loosely speaking, Lipschitz conditions along with finite variation of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are sufficient.  I'm interested in a slightly different problem: given a solution, are the parameters unique?

Assume that $x$ follows some stochastic process
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma dZ_t$$
where $\mu(\cdot)$ is unknown but $\sigma$ is known; and $Z_t$ is a Brownian motion.
Given an initial distribution $f_0(x)$ and a final distribution $f_T(x)$ (observed at time $T$), in what sense is $\mu$ unique?  Can there be multiple $\mu$, differing on a set of positive measure that generate the same final distribution?

I tried to proceed by contradiction and assume there exist two solutions, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, which generate solutions $f_1$ and $f_2$ that agree at $t = 0, T$. It is sufficient to consider the case where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are equal no where on $(0, T)$ and only at $t=0, T$, as otherwise you can consider the problem starting at the point where they are equal.  Furthermore, they cannot be equal everywhere, as this violates the existence of a unique weak solution given parameters (the first point I mentioned above).  However, no obvious contradiction emerged.

I didn't find a solution looking through Stroock & Varadhan's textbook and Rogers & Williams' textbook, but it seems like the statement ought to be true (no obvious counterexample has surfaced).

Comment: A Brownian motion, updated the post to clarify

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking for, but nevertheless you might be interested in the following article: https://hal-amu.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01471568/document

Comment: @saz Thank you, that was very interesting.  This is consistent with my intuition that if you took T to be very small, you basically have an estimate of $\frac{df}{dt}$.  Converting using Feynman-Kac to a PDE would then uniquely pin down the $\mu$ function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Take two bridges of your liking such as a Brownian Bridge (with a sigma on hte brownian part of the diuffusion equation) which starts 0 and ends at 0 at time t=1, then take any other bridge with the same start and end point and with the same Brownian parameter in the diffusion (to construct alternative bridge you can use the h-transform (you seem to be a reader of Rogers and Williams textbook you can have a look there where this subject it is treated unless mistaken) where you can see that such a transform do not alter the diffusion part only the drift part and you are done.

Then you have in the simplest case regarding $f_0$ and $f_1$ (i.e. dirac masses) a systematic way to have counterexamples.

Regards

Comment: I believe this is an argument that there isn't a strong solution, as it relies upon a given Brownian Bridge.  I'm still unsure that there isn't a weak solution, which is closer to my area of interest (hence my phrasing the initial and terminal conditions in terms of distributions).

Comment: To amend my first reply, the proposed counterexample relies on the diffusion being a Brownian Bridge, which is more structure than I'd like to put on the diffusion.  I had assumed the diffusion to be a standard Brownian motion, and so I don't see how it would generalize to that case.

Comment: Also, the drift of the Brownian bridge is time dependent, contrary to the original problem proposed.

Comment: I think that John's comment is really deep and implies that you have no choice in the distribution $f_T$ once $\mu$ ( and $f_0$), is fixed implying unicity that Shffl is looking for I will try to have look if I can spare some time but I don't know if this conjecture is true or if I can prove it. Best regards

Comment: Necro-esque follow up @TheBridge, did you ever come up with an answer to this?  I've thought about it more and it seems like additional assumptions are necessary.  For example, the case in which you have a point mass at 0 as the initial distribution, and a normal distribution at time T as the terminal distribution, can be explained by any process which is a Brownian motion w.r.t the filtration.  It seems like a non-degenerate initial distribution is important to unicity.

Comment: no sorry about that and I do not see any approach to tackle the issue at this time